# Revert Record Page setting from Beta View to Normal Lightning View

Tags: lightning, record-page-setting

I have changed the Opportunity Record Page View in Beta View and now I want to revert the view to normal Lightning view.

What I did to change the Lightning view to Beta View:

1. Search Record Page Setting in Setup.
2. Select the Full View(Beta) as a Default view.
3. Click Save.
4. I selected only Opportunity Object.
5. Opportunity Lightning Record page view changed to Beta View.

Now I want to revert it back to Normal Lightning View.

1. Search Record Page Setting in Setup.
2. Select the Grouped View.
3. Click Save.
4. **Not able to find Opportunity Object, so that I can change the Opportunity View to Normal Lightning view.**

What steps I should follow to convert the Opportunity Record View from Full Beta View to Normal Lightning View? Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_records_record_page_view_set.htm&type=5)

> The new view applies to the objects you select and all objects that
>   don’t have specific custom assignments. The custom pages for the
>   selected objects are unassigned as part of this process but you can
>   reassign them in the Lightning App Builder.

So,

**Explanation:** Only those objects which have custom record page (flexi-page) assignments will appear to select (to override) on **Save**. So, initially you had custom page assigned for **Opportunity** which made it appear in list for override. When you selected it, your opportunity **does not** have custom assignment and has standard `Full View`. So, when you go to setup to change the view, you will not see Opportunity anymore because it has standard view assigned.

**Solution**:

1. You can go to [Opportunity Lightning Record Pages in Object Manager](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=extend_click_find_objectmgmt_lex.htm&type=5) and assign the custom record page
2. Although Opportunity is not available for selection, if you save it Opportunity will have standard Grouped View assigned

Comment: Thanks for the answer @salesforce-sas, Can you please suggest how can I revert  my Opportunity Page View to earlier without creating any custom Record Page.

Comment: Check the 1st point. Go to link in it. You will find your custom record page there. Go to your record page and assign again